# intermittent "unable to connect to remote server" error

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, connectivity

I'm running a windows service which downloads RSS feeds using the following code:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };

string feedXml = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(url, settings));
```

The service doesn't run under IIS but as an independent service.

All of the sudden (I suspect an infrastructural problem) we started receiving "unable to connect to remote server" every 10-20 minutes.
The code itself hasn't changed and I'm looking for possible causes.

In an attempt to solve this, I moved the service to a different machine but the problem persisted.

Would love to get any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this was that the exact same service was installed in a different machine in the same environment, causing two different IPs to connect to the RSS feeds. Depending on the intervals, sometimes it was OK, sometimes it was blocked by the RSS provider.